# Full screen background HTML5 video with cover image

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I'm trying to add full screen background video to my site. I want to add a cover image too, because on mobile devices the video just does not play (because without user interaction the browser just won't load it).

So I added the video, positioned it properly, then I added the image. The image is the first frame of the video. Here is the problem: the position of the video and the image is not the same. So first the user sees the cover image, then after a moment the video starts playing, but there is a jump, because the video is not positioned the same as the image. Please note you may need to resize the browser window to see the problem. On 1920x1080 resolution it is barely visible.

How to position the video and the cover image properly?

See the demo code below. The video starts playing after 2 seconds, so you can see the image and then the video.

Here is a [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAWktz9doy4) in which you see the image and then the paused video, the [cover image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQrD1.jpg) and the [video](http://www.filedropper.com/palmtrees).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        div,
        video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .video {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            z-index: 1;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .panel-cover {
            position: fixed;
            background-image: url(cover.jpg);
            z-index: 2;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="background-video" class="video" muted loop preload="auto">
        <source src="Palm_Trees.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="panel-cover"></div>
    <script>
        (function () {
            function playVideo(video) {
            setTimeout (function () {
                video.play();
                document.querySelector(".panel-cover").style.background = 'none';
                }, 2000);
            }

            window.onload = function () {
                var video = document.querySelector("#background-video");
                video.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
                    playVideo(video);
                }, false);

                if (video.readyState > 3) {
                    playVideo(video);
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really the aspect ratio of the video. It's not 1:1, but 16:9.

So:

1. Removed Javascript, added the `autoplay` attribute. The video is a child of the cover image's div. If the video starts playing, the cover image won't be visible, if not, then the cover image will be visible.
2. Width/Height of the video and the cover image. It depends on the aspect ratio of the video and the browser window. So once you need `width: 100%; height: auto;` and in other cases you need the opposite: `width: auto; height: 100%;`

Therefore I added the appropriate `@media` queries:

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9)
```

If you have a simple 1:1 video, then maybe it just doesn't matter.

The final solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        div,
        video {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .video {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            z-index: -100;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .video-cover {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -200;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(cover.jpg);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
            .video {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }

        @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
            .video {
                width: auto;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="video-cover">
        <video class="video" muted loop autoplay preload="auto">
            <source src="Palm_Trees.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on one of my sites so will just paste you full code and you can adjust to your needs.

```
<div class="bgBox">
    <div class="bgBox__cover cover_60"></div>
    <div class="bgBox__holder" style="background-image: url('PATH/TO/IMAGE/COVER');">

        <video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" class="bgBox__video">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="PATH/TO/VIDEO">
        </video>

    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.bgBox {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

.bgBox__cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cover_60 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.bgBox__holder {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.bgBox__video {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -khtml-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-filter: "alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -ms-opacity: 1;
    -o-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Image needs to have the same aspect ration as the video.

Comment: Sadly this does not work properly, see this demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAWktz9doy4. The first is the cover image, then you see the first frame of the video. Its clearly not the same, there is the "jump".

Comment: This is awkward. Here is a full example with video and image http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=37298396476495665943
All as in code I pasted above - so perhaps this is an issue with image or video aspect ratios or something like this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Unfortunately it is not working for my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hbCeILh_1U. First I show the problem: do you see the "jump"? Then I show the image and the video, as I see they are the same. Your video's aspect ratio is 4:3 I think, mine is 16:9? Maybe that's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a simple workaround: slowly fading out the cover image:

```
.panel-cover {
    ...
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

document.querySelector(".panel-cover").style.opacity = 0;
```